# Teenage girl enters a suburbian hippie commune and is found there by her parents

Tags: identify-this-movie

I watched this movie by chance on German TV supposedly sometime in the 2000s, missed the beginning and failed to note it's title. I searched IMDb for movies with the keyword 'commune' but did not find it. I liked it pretty much for it's authenticity. Maybe someone recognizes it and knows the title?

**Time and place**
From the way people were dressed and behaved I guess the movie is set in the 70s. I remember almost only scenes around the house so I don't know about shops or other public places.
The few cars I spotted and the way houses looked were a bit different from what I am used from US movie locations of that period so I think it might take place in Canada or Australia.
Guessed from the optical appearance of the picture and the overall look the movie itself could have been shot in the 70s or 80s.

**General contents**
Basically the movie follows the everyday life of some 10-15 (?) people in their 20s (?) forming a hippie style commune. They live in a somewhat bigger house located (somewhat uphill?) in a kind of middle class housing area of what might be either a small town or suburb.
At least partly they are musicians and other artists and the movie depicts lots of the typical discussions and quarrels (at times somewhat lengthy) between people being on a mission to find and explore themselves and how to relate with each other. I am quite sure drugs and lack of money were key points, too.

**Subplot mentioned in this question's title**
I don't remember any real plot except what happens towards the end of the movie: A teenage girl shows up and wants to stay at the commune. A little love story unfolds, conflicts arise. At some point her conservative parents show up to take her home. I am not sure whether she leaves with them or walks away on her own some time later on.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you may be describing the movie **[Sign of Aquarius](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0066007/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1)** 1970, also known as Love Commune or Ghetto Freaks.

The film is sorta plotless as it mainly follows the daily lives of a group of hippies who live in a communal apartment. The group encounters police, they protest and engage in drug use etc.

Parts of the subplot match as far as the young girl running away from her parents home to join the commune.

I found a trailer for the film online, hopefully it's the one you're looking for:

Comment: Unfortunately this is _not_ the movie I'm searching for (which is much less dramatic than "Sign of Aquarius"). Yet it seems like a movie I'd like to watch some time. Anyway, thanks @tohood87 for taking time 'n'effort proposing this one and even finding the trailer.

Comment: @wmelonman - ahhh that's a shame,  sorry that it wasn't the one you were looking for. Hopefully someone else might be able to help find it :)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds a bit like [Dogs In Space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dogs_in_Space).  This was an '86 Australian movie starring INXS' lead singer Michael Hutchence.  Like Sign of Aquarius, the film is sorta plotless as it mainly follows the daily lives of a group of hippies and musos who live in a communal house in suburban Melbourne.

Lack of money and drug use are prevalent (and a large plot device toward the end of the movie).  There is a runaway, but interaction with her parents (as I remember) doesn't play a significant part.

Trailer link:

Comment: No, even though from the description it seems very likely, yet it's definitely not the movie I am searching for, it is way too 80s. Maybe this one is a remake of mine? The Youtube clips did give me some deja vu moments... Anyway, thanks a lot for posting this, @mcalex!